# Create Table columns must be named - DBT/BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, dbt

I have this repo, which was built using dbt-core to work with my Postgres db for a personal project.

I ended getting a job in which i had to get this code from my local machine to a production environment.

I thought I would just clone the repo into dbt cloud and it would work with BigQuery, but no.

The error I'm getting is

```
Database Error in model user_insights (models/instagram/user_insights.sql)
  CREATE TABLE columns must be named, but column 7 has no name at [12:7]
```

I don't get it, because I didn't found a CREATE TABLE anywhere. [Here's the repo](https://github.com/beginsocialmedia/dbt-begin)

I have 4 models, 2 of them had this same problem, the other 2 worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Looking further into the models I found that the problems were that I was using double quotation marks, since it was necessary when working with dbt core (Python) and that was causing crashes since now it only expects SQL code.

Just removing it resolved the problem.

Comment: Just to add a little help with debugging, when you run/compile a model, check your `target` folder. It will have the compiled model (with all resolved refs and macros compiled into pure SQL), as well as the run model (with DDL language, such as 'CREATE TABLE`).